# How to sort a csv file on a field that contains double data type value on Java?

Tags: java, sorting, csv

I have a CSV file that contains something like this:

```
A,B,C,1.23
D,E,F,3.51
G,H,I,0.45
```

I have stored the lines of the CSV files in an `ArrayList<String>`.

I want to sort it by descending order, so it will be like this:

```
D,E,F,3.51
A,B,C,1.23
G,H,I,0.45
```

How can I do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In comparator do O2 compare with O1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) and pass in your own comparator:

```
ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
lines.add("A,B,C,1.23");
lines.add("D,E,F,3.51");
lines.add("G,H,I,0.45");
Collections.sort(lines, Comparator.comparingDouble(e -> -Double.parseDouble(e.split(",")[3])));
```

result:

```
D,E,F,3.51
A,B,C,1.23
G,H,I,0.45
```